# MySQL forgot about automatically creating an index for a foreign key?

Tags: mysql, database-design, indexing, foreign-keys, innodb

After running the following SQL statements, you will see that, MySQL has automatically created the non-unique index `question_tag_tag_id_tag_id` on the `tag_id` column for me after the **first** `ALTER TABLE` statement has run.

But after the **second** `ALTER TABLE` statement has run, I think MySQL should also automatically create another non-unique index `question_tag_question_id_question_id` on the `question_id` column for me.

But as you can see from the `SHOW INDEXES` statement output, it's not there.

Why does MySQL forget about the **second** `ALTER TABLE` statement?

By the way, since I have already created a unique index `question_id_tag_id_idx` used by **both** `question_id` and `tag_id` columns. Is creating a separate index for each of them redundant?

```
mysql> DROP DATABASE mydatabase;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE DATABASE mydatabase;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> USE mydatabase;
Database changed
mysql> CREATE TABLE question (id BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT, html TEXT, PRIMARY KEY(id)) ENGINE = INNODB;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.05 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE tag (id BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT, name VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL, UNIQUE INDEX name_idx (name), PRIMARY KEY(id)) ENGINE = INNODB;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.05 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE question_tag (question_id BIGINT, tag_id BIGINT, UNIQUE INDEX question_id_tag_id_idx (question_id, tag_id), PRIMARY KEY(question_id, tag_id)) ENGINE = INNODB;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> ALTER TABLE question_tag ADD CONSTRAINT question_tag_tag_id_tag_id FOREIGN KEY (tag_id) REFERENCES tag(id);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.10 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> ALTER TABLE question_tag ADD CONSTRAINT question_tag_question_id_question_id FOREIGN KEY (question_id) REFERENCES question(id);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.13 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> SHOW INDEXES FROM question_tag;
+--------------+------------+----------------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| Table        | Non_unique | Key_name                   | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment |
+--------------+------------+----------------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| question_tag |          0 | PRIMARY                    |            1 | question_id | A         |           0 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| question_tag |          0 | PRIMARY                    |            2 | tag_id      | A         |           0 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| question_tag |          0 | question_id_tag_id_idx     |            1 | question_id | A         |           0 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| question_tag |          0 | question_id_tag_id_idx     |            2 | tag_id      | A         |           0 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| question_tag |          1 | question_tag_tag_id_tag_id |            1 | tag_id      | A         |           0 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
+--------------+------------+----------------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
5 rows in set (0.01 sec)

mysql>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html):

> There must be an index where the
>   foreign key columns are listed as the
>   first columns in the same order. Such
>   an index is created on the referencing
>   table automatically if it does not
>   exist.

`question_id` is the first column of both the primary key and the `question_id_tag_id_idx` index. Therefore, no further index is needed for the foreign key. The `question_id_tag_id_idx` index is actually unnecessary because the primary key has the same columns in the same order. Primary keys are unique [clustered indexes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-index-types.html).

For the `question_tag_tag_id_tag_id` foreign key, an index is created because there is no existing index starting with `tag_id`.

The reason that the `question_id_tag_id_idx` index (or the primary key) can be used for the foreign key on `question_id`, but not for the foreign key on `tag_id` is explained by the section on [how MySQL uses indexes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html) in the documentation:

> If the table has a multiple-column
>   index, any leftmost prefix of the
>   index can be used by the optimizer to
>   find rows. For example, if you have a
>   three-column index on (col1, col2,
>   col3), you have indexed search
>   capabilities on (col1), (col1, col2),
>   and (col1, col2, col3).

The foreign key needs to be able to quickly look up values in the referencing table (`question_tag`). `question_id` appears first in `question_id_tag_id_idx` (is a leftmost prefix),  so this index can be used. `tag_id` appears second, so the index cannot be used.

Comment: I see, this means I don't have to create `question_id_tag_id_idx` index because `question_id` column is one of the left-most prefix patterns in the clustered indexes, which can already be used to look up a record in `question_tag` table by a question id quickly. But  `tag_id` column is not, that's why it needs a separate index for fast lookup in `question_tag` table by a tag id. Is this correct?

Comment: @bobo `question_id_tag_id_idx` is not needed because it just duplicates the primary key. A separate index is needed for `tag_id` because it doesn't appear at the start of the `question_id_tag_id_idx` index or the primary key.

Answer (score 1):

In a multicolumn index, I believe you get the first column's index for free as if there were an index on only that column.

Update: This is only the case on specific indexes as the other answerer pointed out, that are non-null and become "clustered indexes".